# Custom Unity EditorWindow forgets selected GameObjects/Components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When making a custom EditorWindow in Unity, I have variables of multiple types (Enums, bools, ints, strings etc) as well as an InputField. Of course, when you enter values, they are forgotten when you restart Unity. So to get around this, I have created an additional class to hold the values.

This works for all the types (bools, ints, strings, enums etc), but I don't know how to save an assignment for unity components such as InputField for example.

Below is the code I have created, all of which works, but when I restart Unity, **I need to find a way for the Tool to not forget the object assigned from Hierarchy in inputField.**

```
public class Tool : EditorWindow
{
    public InputField inputField;
    private bool myBool = true;
    private string myString = "Hello World";

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        inputField = (InputField)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Input Field", inputField, typeof(InputField), true);
        GetRestApiMain.myBool = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Bool", GetRestApiMain.myBool );
        GetRestApiMain.myString = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Hello World", GetRestApiMain.myString);
    }
}

public class ToolReferences
{
    /* public static InputField inputField ?
     * {
     *     I don't know what to do here to save the InputField set by the user
     *     All the below works, and want to have the same for InputField
     *     whereby the assignment is not forgotten on restart.
     * } */

    public static bool myBool 
    {
        get
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            return EditorPrefs.GetBool("Bool", false);
#else
            return false;
#endif
        }

        set
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            EditorPrefs.SetBool("Bool", value);
#endif
        }
    }

    public static string myString 
    {
        get
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            return EditorPrefs.GetString("Hello World", "");
#else
        return false;
#endif
        }
        set
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            EditorPrefs.SetString("Hello World", value);
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this was to get the InstanceID of the object in `OnGUI();` in the main class. Then store the ID in a static int in the other class, not a `static InputField`. Below is the working code. 
(*thank you @milan-egon-votrubec for the InstanceID pointer*)

This will not let you remove your assignment until you set the int to `0`, but you can replace it, and it will save after restart. I'm sure there is a better solution, but for now, this works after testing in multiple scenarios without error in a single scene. If you change the scene, it will loose it's assignment unless you use a prefab.

ToolReferences class...

```
 // class ToolReferences
 public static int inputFieldId
    {
        get
        {
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
            return EditorPrefs.GetInt("inputFieldId", 0);
 #else
            return false;
 #endif
        }

        set
        {
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
            EditorPrefs.SetInt("inputFieldId", value);
 #endif
        }
    }
```

Then in the Tool class...

```
 public class Tool : EditorWindow
 {
      public InputField inputField;
      // ...
      public void OnGUI()
      {
           inputField = (InputField)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Input Field", inputField, typeof(InputField), true);
           // if inputField has nothing currently assigned
           if (inputField == null)
           {
                // make sure we have and int stored
                if (ToolReferences.inputFieldId != 0)
                {
                     inputField = (InputField)EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(ToolReferences.inputFieldId);
                }
                else // ... prompt the user to assign one
           }
           // if we have an InputField assigned, store ID to int
           else if (inputField != null) ToolReferences.inputFieldId = inputField.GetInstanceID();
           }
       } 
 // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the InputField `InstanceID` to `EditorPrefs`, by passing in your InputField instance, and then retrieve it in reverse:

```
public static InputField GetInputField
{
  get
  {
    return EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(EditorPrefs.GetInt("InputFieldId"));
  }
  set
  {
    EditorPrefs.GetInt("InputFieldId", value.GetInstanceID());
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to have a cast, `return (InputField)EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(EditorPrefs.GetInt("InputFieldId"));` and use `value.GetInstanceID()` (fixed typo and added cast for anyone who is copypasta). It always returns null and can't assign inputField in editor. Interesting approach though.